# Server becomes down after trying restart

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php

The problem I am facing is that, when I try to restart "code" server using command `sudo init 6`, the server Shuts down.I could'nt even connect the server.How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: What does /etc/init.d/apache2 status return? Also please describe your problem in more detail. Your post is not written in a way we can understand what the problem is.

Comment: On many OSes, `init 6` is designed to reboot the OS.  The server going down is a feature, not a bug.  If you don't want the server to reboot, it's probably best to stop rebooting it.

Comment: @MadHatter so how can I stop the rebooting process?

Comment: In general, don't do `init 6`.  If you mean "Now I've done `init 6`, how do I get the server back?", you will need to wait for it to reboot.  Why it's not rebooting properly is a different question entirely.  If it's local, put a console on it and see what it's doing; if it's remote, the question probably need to be addressed to the hosting company and/or colo facility where the server is.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to restart your system, try reboot command.

And to troubleshoot the reason of the problem, you need to check the log messages, that what happens at the end,when the system actually needs to reboots, but it shuts down. Logs will give you a clue.

Here is an interesting article on difference of reboot command and "init 6"

> In Linux, the init 6 command gracefully reboots the system running all
>   the K* shutdown scripts first, before rebooting.  The reboot command
>   does a very quick reboot.  It doesn’t execute any kill scripts, but
>   just unmounts filesystems and restarts the system.  The reboot command
>   is more forceful.
>
> So, should I use reboot or init 6?  – neither!  My advice is to use
>   the shutdown command.  shutdown will do a similar job to init 6, but
>   it has more options and a better default action.  Along with kicking
>   off an init 6, the shutdown command will also notify all logged in
>   users (logged in at a tty), notify all processes the system is going
>   down and by default will pause  for a set time before rebooting
>   (giving you the chance to cancel the reboot if you realize that you
>   made a mistake).

http://www.vreference.com/2009/09/23/reboot-is-not-the-same-as-init-6/

Comment: Second the "use shutdown". Do not use reboot or init 6. You want programs to close to prevent corrupted databases or worse.